# Finding on each folder if a subfolder respect the convention name according to the folder name?

Tags: linux, command-line, string

i have a "sites" folder with a number of site folder named:

- `bu.my-url.com`
- `dud.myurl.com`
- `[must-be-indentical_string].myurl.com`
- etc

On each site folder, I'd like to check if the `/themes/amu_[must-be-indentical_string]` is identical to the site folder name

```
/sites/[must-be-indentical_string].myurl.com/themes/amu_[must-be-indentical_string]
```

Would there be a command for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
cd /path/to/sites || exit
ret=0
for file in */themes/amu_*; do
  [ -e "$file" ] || continue
  dir=${file%%/*}
  theme=${file##*/amu_}
  case $dir in
    ("$theme".*) ;; # OK
    (*) printf>&2 '%s\n' "Mismatch: $file"
        ret=1;;
  esac
done
exit "$ret"
```

With GNU `find`, see also:

```
cd /path/to/sites &&
  find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -regextype posix-basic \
    -path './*/themes/amu_*' \
    ! -regex '\./\(.*\)\..*/themes/amu_\1' \
    -fprintf /dev/stderr 'Mismatch: %P\n'
```

Comment: can we also make sure that the folder name starts with "amu_" ?